# Update dependencies to external Cargo.toml package

Tags: rust

I am working on a Rust project that pulls another Rust package having a dependency crate ‘cargo-platform’ that is kept on a local repository.The crate in the external package is expressed the following line shown below.

```
[dependenies]
cargo-platform = { path = "crates1/cargo-platform"}
```

I have multiple versions of this crate on my machine and I would like to update the path of this crate of the external package dynamically from my Rust program.

So for example, after one iteration, the dependency will get updated to on the external package.

```
[dependenies]
cargo-platform = { path = "../cargo-platform"}
```

Is something like this possible from Rust.I have searched quite a bit but all libraries seem to modify or edit the current manifest I am on.

Comment: It not really clear what you want to accomplish. Maybe providing an dependency tree and how you want it to be modified would help.

Comment: *"update the path of this crate of the external package dynamically from my Rust program"* - I'm uncertain what you mean with that. Rust isn't an interpreted language, it's a compiled language. The binary doesn't know its source code any more. I feel like there is a misunderstanding somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible only in local.

For me, you have to publish your dependency 'crates1' and next you just have to add it in your Cargo.toml dependencies.
If you have to update something, just upgrade the version and that's ok.

The other possibility is to call the dependency in a git repository.

```
[dependencies]
crates1 = { git = "https://github.com/your-pseudo/crates1" }
```

Then you have just to update your git repository with new code and your app will retrieve it.

Hope it helps :)